# Making Restaurant Reservations in Paris from America

Tags: online-resources, france, paris, restaurants

Is there a service that makes reservations at restaurants on your behalf?  I'm not a fluent French speaker so I'd rather not spend the money calling long distance from America only to not be able to communicate with the restaurant.

The restaurant I'd like to dine at isn't on opentable or any other restaurant reservation sites I've found so far that serve Paris.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The Fork](http://www.thefork.com/) is incredible service. But there are some nice places that are not listed there, so you should find their site and some of them allow booking online. Actually you can call using Skype and it will cost you cents.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer since The Fork seems like a really great site.  It didn't have my particular restaurant though :(

Answer (score 7):

If you have an American Express account they can do reservations worldwide for you.

Also some apps on iPhone/iPad can do that, I know one called *Red Butler* but I'm sure there are many others.

Some mobile phone companies do that but I don't think that's available in the US.

And of course you can just arrive in Paris and let your hotel do that for you.

Comment: Hi @msk, you've made some good contributions but good English style and formatting seems to help Stack Exchange. I've been editing a few of your things to capitalize the sentences and first person pronouns.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that was so important.

Comment: I think they feel it's important because the questions will remain here forever and become references for people in the coming years with similar questions. Thus they want it to be professional and high quality.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that was so important. Also this happens when you try to learn too many languages, they all get mixed up in your head. I seem to forget the proper way for each language, and then I think at least I am understood.